# AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'yaxis'

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Can anyone help me understand this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'yaxis'
```

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import warnings as wrn
from Data_Science.Category_Data_Types import movies
wrn.filterwarnings('ignore')

sns.set_style('whitegrid')

axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
sns.kdeplot(movies.BudgetMillions, movies.AudienceRating, ax=axes[0])
sns.kdeplot(movies.BudgetMillions, movies.CriticRating, ax=axes[1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.subplots` returns the figure and axes objects. You need to do `fig, axes = plt.subplots(...)` instead

Comment: k, lemme try that

Comment: thanks error fixed

Answer (score 1):

change the relevant line to -

```
_, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))
```

The first output is the `figure` object, so when you refer to `axes[0]` you're actually inputting a `figure` object, which justifiably has no `yaxis` attribute.